# Dynamically added divs overflow their container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

tl;dr look at http://jsfiddle.net/1f6j3o5u/1/ - why are the original checkboxes neatly wrapped but the dynamically added ones overflow?

---

I have several checkboxes that should wrap inside their container and their labels must not "break off". My solution that works is this: wrap every checkbox in a `div`:

```
<div class="filterlabel">
  <input type="checkbox" id="test1" />
  <label for="test1">test 1</label>
</div>
```

The relevant style is:

```
div.filterlabel {
  display: inline;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Everything works fine if the checkboxes/divs are statically added. However, if I add them in e.g. a loop using jQuery, they stop wrapping and simply escape the container...

```
for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
  ($("<div></div>", {
    'class': 'filterlabel'
  }).append($("<input/>", {
    'type': 'checkbox',
    'id': 'othertest' + i
  })).append($("<label></label>", {
    'for': 'othertest' + i
  }).text("test " + i))).appendTo($('#Container'));
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Are the dynamically added divs somehow different? Inspecting their styles in a browser suggests that there should be absolutely no difference...

Comment: How about using `display: inline-block` instead of `display: inline`?

Comment: Yes, tested with inline-block and it works fine.

Comment: It does indeed help, could anyone clarify why `inline-block` does the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with rendering inline elements. `Display: inline-block;` should help:
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/1f6j3o5u/6/)

Comment: Could you clarify/link to the problem explanation?

Comment: Currently I could not find anything related to this problem, but I guess this comes from browser's rendering engine and how he deals with no-wrap on inline elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
  ($("<div></div>", {
    'class': 'filterlabel',
    'style': 'display:inline-block'
  }).append($("<input/>", {
    'type': 'checkbox',
    'id': 'othertest' + i
  })).append($("<label></label>", {
    'for': 'othertest' + i
  }).text("test " + i))).appendTo($('#Container'));
}
```